# Decorator to pass instance and class to method

Tags: python, python-3.x

In some of my [peewee](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/)-based ORM models, I need to access the instance as well as the respective class.
Since I caught myself always repeating the line `cls = self.__class__` at the top of each such methods, I wrote a decorator for that:

```
def with_class(function):
    """Adds the instance's class as second
    parameter to the wrapped function.
    """

    @wraps(function)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Wraps the given function."""
        return function(self, self.__class__, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

**Example use case:**

```
class Location(_TerminalModel):
    """Location of a terminal."""

    address = CascadingFKField(Address, column_name='address')
    annotation = CharField(255, null=True)

    …

    @with_class
    def save_unique(self, cls, *args, **kwargs):
        """Saves the location if it is new or
        returns the appropriate existing record.
        """
        if self.annotation is None:
            annotation_selector = cls.annotation >> None
        else:
            annotation_selector = cls.annotation == self.annotation

        try:
            return cls.get((cls.address == self.address) & annotation_selector)
        except cls.DoesNotExist:
            self.save(*args, **kwargs)
            return self
```

I'd like to have critique on this solution and am open to alternatives.

Comment: So, you saved typing a single line at the expense of typing a single line? :-\

Comment: @bipll Good point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend not using `value.__class__`. This is as [it's not guaranteed to return the type](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes).

> `type(x)` is typically the same as `x.__class__` (although this is not guaranteed – a new-style class instance is permitted to override the value returned for `x.__class__`).

Take:

```
class A:
    __class__ = 'something'

print(A.__class__)   # <class 'type'>
print(A().__class__) # 'something'
print(type(A()))     # <class '__main__.A'>
```

I also think just using `type` would be cleaner, and easier to understand.

```
def save_unique(self, *args, **kwargs):
    cls = type(self)
```